# Swift - Add UIRefreshControl to section header view of table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to add a UIRefresh control to the section header table depending on a flag, however it is not showing up, can somebody see the reason?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    ...
    let textAttribs = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 16.0)!]
    if appsAreGettingInstalled {  
            let titleString = NSAttributedString(string: "Apps are getting installed", attributes: textAttribs)
            let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width - 20, height: 40))
            lbl.attributedText = titleString

            let refreshCtrl = UIRefreshControl()
            refreshCtrl.beginRefreshing()

            let view = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: tableView.bounds.size.width - 20, height: 40))
            view.addSubview(refreshCtrl)
            view.addSubview(lbl)

            headerView.addSubview(view)
     }
     ...
}
```

I also tried `view.refreshControl = refreshCtrl` but it's still not shown, only the label.

Comment: I don't know why you need to use `UIRefreshControl` here. Simply, you can use an `UIActivityIndicator`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that widget, thank you. Solved the problem

Comment: @phoebus Glad to see you were able to get this answered. Please delete this question or post an answer to indicate resolution.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a simple way of adding refresh control through Interface builder.

First, select the tableViewController in your storyboard, open the attribute inspector, and enable refreshing

[image: Please check below image for more clarity]

Now in your viewdidLoad add following code:

```
self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.refreshLogic(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Finally, refreshLogic function may look like following:

```
func refreshLogic(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

  // Insert your logic here do some reloading of data and update the table view's data source

  // reload your table

   self.yourTableViewObj.reloadData
   refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

I think this can also work for you. **Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

As trungduc suggested, using an activity indicator view instead of the refresh control solved my issue - thanks